# Loop through 1 data frame and add the result to another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a data frame (df) of football results (soccer) and from that, I've created another data frame (homeformdf) which I want to use to look at the first 5 home team results for each unique entry.
The output I require is a sum of home team goals scored.

The df looks like this:
[image]

The homeformdf like this:
[image]

For each row in homeformdf, I want to look at df and sum the first 5 home games 'home_team_goals_count' from df.

The resulting sum needs to be added to the homeformdf as a new column 'HG'

My thought would be for:

- a loop to use the home_team_name from homeformdf
- match the first instance in df home_team_name
- place the home_team_goal_count in homeformdf
- add 1 to a counter
- and move down a row in df

This would repeat until the counter hits 5 and then another loop initiated to move the home_team_name from hometeamdf down 1 row, and repeat until the end row.

I appreciate I may not be as forthcoming with attempted code as you would like, so advice on how best to approach this would be massively appreciated because I'm going around in search circle looking for an answer - and not even knowing if I'm thinking about this right.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you want your output df to look like but you should never loop through dataframes row by row.

Comment: Yeah sure. It's in-experience on my part, however thanks for pointing it out. I have the answer which was so much simpler than I was believing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
top_5 = df[['home_team_name', 'home_team_goal_count']].groupby('home_team_name').head(5)
goals_per_home_team = top_5.groupby('home_team_name').sum()
```

There's probably a way to do this in one line but this was what I could get working the quickest.